# Rust Constraints for Generic Type Reference

Tags: generics, reference, constraints, rust

Here's the scenario: I have a structure and trait pair as follows:

```
trait Operation {
    fn operation(self) -> u32
}

struct Container<T: Sized + Operation> {
    x:T
}

impl <T: Sized + Operation> for Container<T> {
    fn do_thing(&self) -> u32 {
        // Do something with the field x.
    }
}
```

The operation requires a pass-by-value call whenever used, and the issue comes with anything similar to "do_thing." I would prefer to not have to enforce copy semantics for the type `T` and would like a workaround for this. Essentially I would like to know the following:

1. Is it possible to enforce trait constraints on references of type parameters? Something along the lines of: `struct Container<T: Sized + Operation> where &T: Operation { ... }`. I've tried mucking with the syntax a bit, and I've not had any success.
2. If the above is not currently possible, is it theoretically possible; i.e. it doesn't violate any require coherence properties or something along those lines?
3. Would it be possible to create a second trait, say `Middle: Operation`, where `Middle` can require that any implementers of `Middle`, `T`, to also be required to implement `Operation` for `&T`.
4. If neither of the above are possible, is there some other common workaround for this?

Some Notes:

- I don't have access to change the `Operation` trait, it's given and it's what I'm to work with.
- There's an [old RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0135-where.md) that talks about some modifications to where clauses, but I didn't find anything related to reference constraints.
- compiler version: *rustc 1.8.0 (db2939409 2016-04-11)*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can restrict `&T` to be `Sized + Operation`. You need to use [Higher-Rank Trait Bounds](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html) and `where`.

```
trait Operation {
    fn operation(self) -> u32;
}

struct Container<T>
    where for<'a> &'a T: Sized + Operation
{
    x: T,
}

impl<T> Container<T>
    where for<'a> &'a T: Sized + Operation
{
    fn do_thing(&self) -> u32 {
        self.x.operation()
    }
}

impl<'a> Operation for &'a u32 {
    fn operation(self) -> u32 {
        *self
    }
}

fn main() {
    let container = Container { x: 1 };
    println!("{}", container.do_thing());
}
```

prints

```
1
```

Comment: This is great. I've read the book multiple times and HRTB have been a source of confusion for me. This answer helped me (and I'm not the OP!). Thanks again!

Comment: They're not currently in the book :( they will be in the second edition

Comment: HRTB can be limiting. The bound `for<'a> &'a T: Operation` implicitly requires `for<'a> T: 'a`, basically that `T: 'static` (contains no borrowed data).